# Albums order in iTunes: order by artist, then by year

Tags: macos, itunes, ordering

I use iTunes (in OSX) with the grid view, and the albums are by default ordered by artist.
Within each artist, the albums are ordered alphabetically by album name.
I'd like to have an ordering by year, so the albums are dsplayed alphabetically by artist and within each artist chronologically by year.

Is this possible? I wasn't able to find a way to achieve this in the preferences or anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

When viewing an individual artist, click on the header for the Album column and it will cycle through a few album organization options, one of them being Album By Year.  Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be a permanent solution, as iTunes tends to default back to Album By Name when you reopen the program.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't think there's a way to do this. However, there *is* a way to make albums organized by year; click the year header until it cycles to "Album by Year". The artist column doesn't cycle like that, though.